# Is there a way to see if a user has exported data?

Tags: reporting, data-export

I have a request to see if a specific user has exported any Salesforce data. Also a request for automatic notifications if a large data export has occurred. is this possible

Comment: You have to have an implicit amount of trust. After all, if they can access salesforce, there's nothing stopping them from even searching for records one by one and grabbing screenshots. Setting your security levels to the appropriate settings, and configuring profiles appropriately, is absolutely necessary.

Comment: I met these guys at Dreamforce -- http://www.elastica.net/2014/10/elastica-announces-securlet-salesforce-appexchange/ - business model is all about risk mitigation of cloud systems

Answer (score 3):

Latest Comment from Salesforce on the idea around it :

With the Winter '15 release, you can now use Event Log Files to understand organizational trends.

See the release notes for more information:
http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_elf.htm#topic-title

Idea : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqQGAA0

Comment: This is a paid feature as far as i see, https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Winter-15-Event-Log-Files&language=en_US